# set data folder location for PApplet triggered through runSketch

Tags: java, clojure, processing

I'm running a Processing sketch (a `PApplet` subclass, created by exporting from a Processing sketch) from Clojure. The basic process is

1. export sketch
2. locate jar files in exported application
3. install these jar files into local maven repo
4. load the libs in clojure using `lein`

The code is in [this GH repo](https://github.com/benswift/clojure-processing-sketch-example/tree/minimal-example), including (reasonably) minimal instructions for how to get set up and reproduce the problem.

Loading basic sketches works, but when I create a sketch which calls e.g. `loadImage()` to load an image from my `data` folder, the sketch can't find it.

I know this is convoluted way to do this - this is partially a learning exercise for me and partially the fact that I'm a lisp guy but not a JVM guy.

Is there any way to dynamically tell the `PApplet` subclass where its data folder is? Or am I stuck putting absolute paths everywhere?

EDIT: Ugh, what a mess. It looks like the problem is that I'm actually wrapping each `PApplet` subclass in a clojure `proxy` (so that I can intercept certain methods and make the various sketches play nice together) but the way Processing finds the data path involves [looking at the ProtectionDomain to find the root source path](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java#L7588), so this won't work as I'm currentyly trying it. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: The sketch already knows where the `data` folder is. You shouldn't have to use absolute paths anywhere. Can you please post a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hi Kevin, I've added more detail - it's a bit more complicated than came across before. Thanks for your help, and I'm not expecting strangers on the internet to solve all my problems for free, so if I can't get it working I'll just hardcode the paths. But if I can, it's hopefully a good resource for others.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you're using maven to link to jars you've exported from Processing, and those jars can't find the sketch directory?

If I were you, I would look int two places:

[The Processing JavaDoc](http://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/) contains a detailed reference on every variable and function in Processing. Particularly check out the `PApplet` class and check out the following:

- ARGS_SKETCH_FOLDER
- selectInput()
- selectOutput()
- sketchFile()
- sketchOutputPath() and sketchOutputStream()
- sketchPath()

I would bet that by either setting the first variable or by overriding some of those functions, you can have Processing look wherever you want.

If you need more detail, [the Processing source](https://github.com/processing/processing/blob/master/core/src/processing/core/PApplet.java) will tell you exactly how Processing uses all of the above.